# Schedule a tournament for games with > 2 competitors per game, all meeting

Tags: combinatorics

Scheduling a league of X Teams/Players playing a game designed for $2$ Teams/Players  for $n$ rounds is no problem. (Like Tennis or Football)

However, if there is a game designed for $2+$ simultaneous competitors, how can I work out how to get each team to play each other once and only once?
(Imagine a notional game of Musical Chairs where only $4$ people can play at a time)

Example.
I have a league with $25$ teams 
We play a game that accommodates $4$ people competing simultaneously.
I want each of the $25$ teams to meet each other exactly once...

Is there a method or algorithm for this kind of situation?

Thanks for your thoughts.